# Using sed from makefile to replace a string with a $ in it

Tags: sed, makefile

I have a simple sed replacement for a text file:

```
sed -i 's/Temp_3/$t0/g' ./somefile.txt
```

When I use it in a bash script everything **works fine**.
However, if I try to use the same line **from a makefile**,
the $t is (probably) expanded into the empty string
(there is no variable called t in the makefile) and
Temp_3 is replaced with 0. What is the best way to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear, please provide more information on same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that make first does its substitutions,
in your case `$t` with nothing, then runs the command.
You can, or should ;), circumvent this problem by changing your command as follows: change `$` with `$$`;
make will substitute the double `$` sign with a single one.

```
sed -i 's/Temp_3/$$t0/g' ./somefile.txt
```